# Navigation drawer with linearlayout implementation which supports all versions of android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer

i am making an android app i want to implement the navigation drawer like the following i.e

1. navigation drawer should overlay the actionbar like in playstore,
2. navigation drawer should be a linear layout (so that i need to add header,listview,footer sort of thing)
3. it should be same in all versions>Android 4.0

i want to implement like the drawer in following image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/raiu4.jpg

Comment: so what is your main problem ?

Comment: Have you seen the Design library? http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: do you mean android 1.6 API 4 or android 4.0 API 14? Anyway you shoud provide concrete problem and show your effort, this is not a *write the code for me* site.

Answer (score 1):

Use this layout for your activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>

   <!-- Your Main Content-->

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Your Header-->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_options_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></ListView>

  <!-- Your Footer-->

</LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And your toolBar layout, `tool_bar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/action_bar_color"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: This is one good working answer for this question. Kindly provide the reason for down voting.